# Ubuntu 12.04 LTS 64 bit No Internet Connect

Tags: networking, internet, ethernet, realtek

Today I decided to try Ubuntu 12.04 LTS via USB on my current Windows 7 machine. I run Ubuntu from USB and select trial. I am unable to connect to the Internet and I'm plugged in using my Ethernet port. As I'm new to Linux I'm unsure how or what information I need to provide to get assistance. I apologize in advance if this question has already been answered, but I was unable to find the answer to my question.

Thanks in advance-

Is this the data helpful? I changed the ip...

```
$ sudo lshw -C nekwork

 description: Ethernet interface
       product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
       vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:08:00.0
       logical name: eth0
       version: 03
       serial: 00:24:1d:11:1e:e1
       size: 100Mbit/s
       capacity: 1Gbit/s
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list rom ethernetphysical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
       configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 driverversion=2.3LK-NAPI duplex=full firmware=rtl_nic/rtl8168d-1.fw ip=172.xx.xx.xxx latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=100Mbit/s
       resources: irq:43 ioport:ae00(size=256) memory:fd2ff000-fd2fffff memory:fd2f8000-fd2fbfff memory:fd200000-fd21ffff


ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ifconfig -a

 Link encap:Ethernet  HWaddr 00:24:1d:11:1e:e1  
          inet addr:172.16.12.150  Bcast:172.16.12.255  Mask:255.255.255.0
          inet6 addr: fe80::224:1dff:fe11:1ee1/64 Scope:Link
          UP BROADCAST RUNNING MULTICAST  MTU:1500  Metric:1
          RX packets:73 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:120 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:1000 
          RX bytes:6918 (6.9 KB)  TX bytes:14667 (14.6 KB)

lo        Link encap:Local Loopback  
          inet addr:127.0.0.1  Mask:255.0.0.0
          inet6 addr: ::1/128 Scope:Host
          UP LOOPBACK RUNNING  MTU:65536  Metric:1
          RX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 frame:0
          TX packets:68 errors:0 dropped:0 overruns:0 carrier:0
          collisions:0 txqueuelen:0 
          RX bytes:4240 (4.2 KB)  TX bytes:4240 (4.2 KB)

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ netstat -rn

Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         172.16.12.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
169.254.0.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.0.0     U         0 0          0 eth0
172.16.12.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0

buntu@ubuntu:~$ ping -c 3 172.16.12.1
PING 172.16.12.1 (172.16.12.1) 56(84) bytes of data.
64 bytes from 172.16.12.1: icmp_req=1 ttl=64 time=0.355 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.12.1: icmp_req=2 ttl=64 time=0.345 ms
64 bytes from 172.16.12.1: icmp_req=3 ttl=64 time=0.346 ms

--- 172.16.12.1 ping statistics ---
3 packets transmitted, 3 received, 0% packet loss, time 1998ms
rtt min/avg/max/mdev = 0.345/0.348/0.355/0.022 ms
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ 

ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping -c 3 www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$
```

`sudo route del -net 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 eth0` then see again with `ping -c 3 www.google.com` and test internet

```
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo route del -net 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 eth0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ sudo route del -net 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 eth0
SIOCDELRT: No such process
ubuntu@ubuntu:~$ ping -c 3 www.google.com
ping: unknown host www.google.com
```

Comment: I added the data from sudo lshw -C network. Thanks in advance Sneetsher.

Comment: I just added the details from your command

Comment: I meant I added xxx. to the ip for the sake of the forum. I have a dynamic IP from comcast.

Comment: ok, same with `ping -c 3 172.16.12.1`  then again for `ping -c 3 www.google.com`

Comment: ok. i added the data from ping -c 3 172.16.12.1 then again for ping -c 3 www.google.com

Comment: `sudo route del -net 169.254.0.0 netmask 255.255.0.0 eth0` then see again with `ping -c 3 www.google.com` and test internet

Comment: I added the data. I'm unable to ping google or use firefox. Does it matter that I'm running Ubuntu from USB on the "try me" version?

Comment: @Sneetsher Thank you for all of your help. I apologize I can't get my internet up and running.

Comment: I finally fixed. I needed to change IP to manual and add an IP address.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that your router is 172.16.12.1, your problem is that your machine doesn't know to send Internet-bound packets there.

route add default gw 172.16.12.1

That will make it send everything not on your LAN out through that address.

If that's not your router, find out what your router's address is and substitute it in.